# bootstrap 4 - place video element starting at the top left position

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Newbie to bootstrap and css. I am trying to place a video element within a row class and would like the video element to start at the top left position of the row. That is, without any margins at the left and top. Right now, I see that the video element is aligned in the middle vertically with space on top.

Ideally I would like the row height to be the same as that of video element. Any suggestions and pointers would be helpful.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <video id="video1" autoplay muted style="width:70%;border:2px;position: relative;top: 0%;"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `p-0, m-0` classes to remove all padding and margins from `row` or `container` eg:`<div class="row ml-0"`. more specifically you can do `ml-0` which is margin-left:0. like `mr-0`, `mb-0`, `mt-0`. same for padding too. video should be on left, i dont know why is it in center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html

```css
#video1{background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row p-0" style="height: 100%;">
        <video id="video1" autoplay muted style="width:70%;border:2px;position: relative;top: 0%;"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```